# Remove Item from validation list if already selected

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I have a list of assets which I am using in a data validation list. I am able to use the standard mehtod to check if its being used with a helper column such the following:

1. `=IF(COUNTIF(Schedule!$B$2:$B$7,A1)>=1,"",ROW())`

and then create  list of the unused names with :

2. `=IF(ROW(A1)-ROW(A$1)+1>COUNT(B$1:B$6),"",INDEX(A:A,SMALL(B$1:B$6,1+ROW(A1)-ROW(A$1))))`

I am then creating a names range using the following:

3. `=OFFSET(Assets!$C$1,0,0,COUNT(Assets!$B$1:$B$6),1)`

All pretty standard. This works well for a single column to apply the data validation. My problem is that I want to be able to apply the data validation across 3 columns. Essentially, if the value is selected in ANY of the 3 columns, I want to remove it from the validation list.

I have tried to substitute the `COUNTIF` function in Line 1., with `COUNTIFS` and multiple criteria / ranges but i cant get it to work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas your formulas may all be plain vanilla you did obscure their application in your project by providing references that don't match. In the end, I just created a competitive system which I must now ask you to adapt to your project.

In my project, I placed all data on the same sheet which is called "Schedule". Because of this, Excel omitted sheet names in the formulas where I didn't expressly insert them. When you adapt my solution, please add the sheet names when you refer to ranges on other tabs.

The list of assets is in the range B4:B9. Cells with data validation are in the range C4:E9, the Helper range is G4:G9 and the range from which the validation list is taken is K4:K9. For this setup this is the required Validation List formula.

`=OFFSET($K$4,0,0,COUNT($G$4:$G$9),1)`

Below is the formula for cell K4, to be copied down to K9.

`=IF(ROW()-ROW(A$4)+1>COUNT(G$4:G$9),"",INDEX($B:$B,SMALL(G$4:G$9,ROW()-ROW(A$4)+1)))`

And here, now, is the formula that has an actual change in it. It now finds the use of an asset name in any of the 3 columns with data validation (C:E).

`=IF(COUNTIF(Schedule!$C$4:$E$9,$B4),"",ROW())`

The simplicity of the solution is disproportionate to the difficulty I had finding it. As I said, I was confused by your referencing. Perhaps you didn't find this easy solution for exactly the same reason and now face an uphill battle yourself. If so, just discard your existing solution and implement the one I provide. It may be too hard to make the two match. If you need any help please let me know.

Comment: Hi Variatus, Thanks so much for your help. Worked like a charm! Apologies for the confusing explanation. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Great it worked for both of us. If you tested my answer and found it working, please do mark it as "Selected".